# Mac external drives with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mount, hfs+

I know someone had already asked a question about mounting HFS+ drives on Ubuntu 16.04, but it was for a server edition. My workstation is not a server. I have however tried every solution proposed to the HFS problem that I found anywhere online. I did install the linux-image-extra:

```
suncrushr:/$ sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-image-extra-4.10.0-37-generic is already the newest version (4.10.0-37.41~16.04.1).
linux-image-extra-4.10.0-37-generic set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
```

When I check if the module exists I don't get any errors, it just returns to the command line:

```
suncrushr:/$ modprobe hfsplus
suncrushr:/$
```

so I take it, the module does indeed exist. However when I check if I have the filesystem listed, I get nothing useful:

```
suncrushr:/$ cat /proc/filesystems | grep hfs
        squashfs
```

and of course when I try to mount an HFS drive I get an error about unknown filesystem. So it's like installed and not installed at the same time. Why do I bother? I was a Mac user for 15 years and that after having lived in SGI Origin world for a good long while and the nature of my research projects leads to a proliferation of external drives. I am fairly new to Linux itself even though I haven't used Windows since Windows for Workgroups. I got me a monster Linux laptop after I killed my MacbookPro. What a breath of fresh air. I was seriously getting sick of MacOS wiping out my /usr/local/ and all my compilers every time my arm was twisted into an upgrade but now I have a bunch of data orphaned on those external HFS drives. Turning journaling off doesn't help. mount still complains that the filesystem is unknown.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Have you installed "exfat"?

Comment: Indeed I have. Both exfat-utils and exfat-fuse are installed and are the newest available version: 1.2.3-1. However exfat also does not show up when I query the /proc/filesystems. Only vfat shows up when I grep for "fat". So it's also in that strange installed/not-installed state.

Comment: hmm, I have no such difficulties using my desktop. I shall review this and let you know if I find a solution.  [don't hold your breath!]

Comment: Not holding my breath. I do have a work-around of sorts. I sacrificed one of my 4Tb drives, split it in half and formatted each half as either ext2 or ext3 (can't remember). Mac sees the first half, Linux sees both. That's the largest one of my drives. So technically I could embark on a huge data conversion project if push reeeeally came to shove. My Mac desktop hasn't croaked yet, so this headache of a project is currently deferred.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved!

Turned out to be a hardware problem and not a software one at all. The OWC external disks are just trash, that's all that that was. MyBook external disks go seamlessly between Linux and Mac, absolutely no problem with cross-mounting and cross-reading/writing.

Don't buy OWC external disks. They are also extremely slow on Linux to the point of being unusable, like transfer rates of under 1Mb/s on USB3.